# Python Script -Tkinter problem - TK doesnt work inside a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a problem here with tkinter. I need to use it within a DEF to call it at various points in my script. But when I do that, the Command function no longer recognizes the TK elements. To explain better, I made 2 codes. The first one works perfect. The second, the TK is inside a function. That second one doesn't work.

Script ok, bellow

```
from tkinter import *

fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Window")

def switch():
    b1["state"] = DISABLED

#--Buttons
b1=Button(fenster, text="Button")
b1.config(height = 5, width = 7)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = Button(text="disable", command=switch)
b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

fenster.mainloop()
```

And here, not ok code, inside a function. That gives de error **NameError: name 'b1' is not defined**

```
from tkinter import *

def switch():
    b1["state"] = DISABLED

def funcao():
    fenster = Tk()
    fenster.title("Window")

    #--Buttons
    b1=Button(fenster, text="Button")
    b1.config(height = 5, width = 7)
    b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    b2 = Button(text="disable", command=switch)
    b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

    fenster.mainloop()

funcao()
```

Please, could you help me?
Best Regards

Comment: `b1` is a local variable of `funcao`. It is not visible in the global scope. You can either pass it as an argument to `switch` or move `switch` definition inside the scope of `funcao`.

Comment: The simplest solution is to add `global b1` at the start of `funcao()`.

Comment: @matszwecja You can also make it a global variable like it was in the first example.

Comment: @TheLizzard ik, but I usually try to avoid `global` wherever possible.

Comment: @matszwecja definition a function inside a function looks worse imo. Also the only reason people avoid global variables is when there can be variable name clashes. If you are using functional programming, it's practically unavoidable to have global variables.

Comment: @TheLizzard Name clashes are far from the only reason. There are also race conditions, hard-to-track side effects and numerous other problems. Functions that are meant for single use only like commands bound to a button or inner methods for decorator are very commonly nested like that and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @matszwecja You sound like you know Haskell. |In python it's fine for functions to have side effects. Also making a variable global isn't going to introduce any race conditions that weren't already present. The only difference between a global/local variable in pythons is from where you can access it, if you can access it from somewhere else, it's not a problem as long as there aren't naming clashes. If you think, I am wrong, make a simple example where there is a problem with a global variable that isn't a name collision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250811/discussion-between-thelizzard-and-matszwecja).

Answer (score 1):

You create the `b1` variable in the `funcao` function, so it is created as `funcao`'s **local** variable. Local variables are accessible only from the function where they are created. In the first example, you created a **global** variable (not in a function) so it is accessible from outside of a function but also inside of any function. There are many solutions, so here is one of them:

For example: using nested functions

```
from tkinter import *

def funcao():

    def switch():
        b1["state"] = DISABLED

    fenster = Tk()
    fenster.title("Window")

    #--Buttons
    b1=Button(fenster, text="Button")
    b1.config(height = 5, width = 7)
    b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    b2 = Button(text="disable", command=switch)
    b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

    fenster.mainloop()
```

This works, because the `switch` function is **inside** the `funcao` function, so you can access the `funcao`'s local variables.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect! I found some solutions here on the forum that make the script work. But your suggestion was the best. Simple, objective and with less code. Exactly how I like it lol. No, that didn't help. That fixed it! LOL Thx a lot.